24.04 installer does not see mSATA drive (solved)
I have a Dell Precision M4800, which was running 22.04 off a 2.5" SATA SSD just fine, however I bought an mSATA drive for it and installed that, and I find that the installer (I'm trying to install 24.04, and have not tried this combination with anything else) does not offer the mSATA drive for installation at all. It doesn't show in the partitioning tool, and if I bring up a shell, sudo fdisk -l | grep /dev/sd it doesn't report the drive's existence.
The BIOS, however does see this device, and reports it like this.

Should I be able to install to this, or is this kind of device not supported? If I should be able to, any suggestions on what to change / tinker with?

When I first tried this, I did not have a network connection (it's a Broadcom network device). However, I tried again with a USB WiFi connection and then the 24.04 installer suggests an update. After loading that update, the mSATA device is successfully identified.
With a little luck, any download of the installation media by the time you read this will work correctly, but if, like me, you prepare an installer disk soon after the release and then use it potentially multiple times later, this might be relevant to you.
